# htaccess with www RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, no-www

I did cross-reference addresses without WWW to a WWW
Now I have a problem, if I delete in the address bar WWW, I get an error

this is a .htaccess:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page_id=$2
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?one_art=$3

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pests.co.il
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your rules and keep 301 redirect rules before internal rewrites:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pests\.co\.il$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.pests.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ ?page_id=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ ?one_art=$3 [L,QSA]
```